# swift でチャット機能を実装するにあたって利用できる pod

Tags: swift, ios

swift でチャット機能を作りたいと思いました。

少しググってみたところ、 firebase + [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) で作るのがよい、という記事をたくさん見掛けたのですが、 JSQMessagesViewController は、公式で deprecated になっている様子です。

#### 質問:

- ios 11, swift でチャットを作る際の UI ライブラリとして利用可能な pod で、 JSQMessagesViewController の代替となるようなものは、どのようなものがあるでしょうか。

  - もしくは、 deprecated だけれども JSQMessagesViewController を使いつづけたほうがひとまずよかったりするのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit) が、おそらく JSQMessagesViewController の後継に該当する様子です。

> In-progress: A community-driven replacement for JSQMessagesViewController https://messagekit.github.io